# How to mount a Samsung galaxy S5?

Tags: usb, android, samsung, phone, debugging

My laptop runs on Ubuntu 12.04 and when trying to connect my phone to access files through the USB port, this comes up:

```
**Unable to mount SAMSUNG_Android**
Error initializing camera: -60: Could not lock the device
```

I've already enabled the USB debugging option in developers options and it's connected as a media device (MTP).

Comment: Use it as USB Media Mass Storage Device instead if there is such a setting available - in 14.04 MTP devices work better, but in 12.04 I've noticed issues (tested with a Samsung Galaxy Tab 4, but same concept that MTP and USB media storage are handled differently)

Comment: You cannot mount modern Android devices such as the S5 as USB mass storage.  The reason is USB mass storage needs exclusive access to the entire partition which needs to be un-mounted on the phone while it's shared, whereas modern Android devices like the S5 do not keep user files in a separate partition that can be un-mounted. It wouldn't be technically possible.  MTP allows sharing files non-exclusively without need to un-mount entire partition.